# javascript waiting for return before proceeding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with my javascript not waiting for the return of the call. I already now that javascript is asynchronous so I would like to know how to make this method call wait for the result. I do not have control over the first two snipper since they are uploaded by the user. I can use jquery or pure javascript. Advance thanks!

I have this javascript call

```
var value = somemethod("cmi.location");
/ /This is not getting set since it does not wait. alerts 'undefined'
alert(value);
```

and somemethod looks something like the code below,

```
function somemethod(element){
var result;
result = API1.GetValue(element);
return result;
}
```

API is a window object instantiated by doing the code below. I have access to the code snippets from this point on.

```
var API1 = new API();
```

API is an object in javascript which looks like this:

```
function API(){

};
API.prototype.GetValue=API_GetValue;

function API_GetValue(parameter){
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    async:false,
    url:"method.do",
    dataType:"xml",
    data: {action: 'getValue', parameter: parameter, value: ''},
    success:function(data){
    //I am getting 0 here
        return $(data).find('search').text();
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function API_GetValue(parameter){
var newdata;
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    async:false,
    url:"method.do",
    dataType:"xml",
    data: {action: 'getValue', parameter: parameter, value: ''},
    success:function(data){
    //I am getting 0 here
        newdata = $(data).find('search').text();
    }
});
return newdata;
}
```

you can also do something like this:

```
function API_GetValue(parameter){
var newdata = $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    async:false,
    url:"method.do",
    dataType:"xml",
    data: {action: 'getValue', parameter: parameter, value: ''}
}).responseText;
return $(newdata).find('search').text();
}
```

Comment: I already tried this but it still does not work. I will try it again, can you let me know why you think this would work?

Comment: cause you should declare the variable that will hold the data outside the ajax call. maybe your problem is still in the $(data).find('search').text(); what exactly the responce look like?

Comment: This will work, but **only** because it's set up as a synchronous call.

Comment: this is the same as his original post, the problem must be in the (data).find('search').text(); statement

Comment: thank you! it seems like it is working. I should have asked the question earlier. Could have saved 6 hours!